# Getting input from String ArrayList and output new strings

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, concatenation

This code should take a String ArrayList and print out a modified version of these strings called "states". For example: The first string "3,3,L" should print MMMCCCL. Currently, when I input the ArrayList goodMoves: ([3,3,L, 1,1,R, 3,2,L, 0,3,R, 3,1,L, 2,2,R, 2,2,L, 3,1,R, 0,3,L, 3,2,R, 1,1,L, 3,3,R]), the code returns the last state in the ArrayList ("MMMCCCR") and not all 11 states:

MMMCCCL

MCR

MMMCCL

CCCR

MMMCL

MMCCR

MMCCL

MMMCR

CCCL

MMMCCR

MCL

MMMCCCR

This is what I have so far:

```
// Testing method   
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int missionaries = 3;
    int cannibals = 3;
    boolean BoatState = true;

    // Add initial state
    goodMoves.add(toString(missionaries, cannibals, BoatState));

    // Call checkBoat and explore
    explore(missionaries, cannibals, BoatState, goodMoves, allMovesMade);

    // Print all steps using helper method
    System.out.println(makePicture(goodMoves));

    // Print the total number of operations made
    String finalMoves = ("Number of moves made: " + (goodMoves.size()-1));
    System.out.println(finalMoves);
}

// Create strings of state spaces
public static String makePicture(ArrayList<String> goodMoves) {

    // Initialize strings
    String missString = "";
    String cannString = "";
    String moveString = "";

    // Use input to create printout
    for (String output: goodMoves) {

        // Get numbers/character at each index of string
        char missNum = output.charAt(0);
        char cannNum = output.charAt(2);
        char boatPos = output.charAt(4);

        // Print number of M's and C's then concatenate them together
        missString = new String(new char[missNum]).replace("\0", "M");
        cannString = new String(new char[cannNum]).replace("\0", "C");

        // Concatenate both strings
        moveString = missString + cannString + boatPos + "\n";
        }
    }
    // Return string of current state
    return moveString;
}
```

Please let me know if there are any clarifications needed. This problem is in reference to the common Missionaries and Cannibals game. Thanks in advance!

*Update: problem solved. Thanks for the feedback*

Comment: Insert System.out.println() statements (may be after each line), This will help you to understand what each line of code is doing and change it accordingly.

Comment: Can you add the part of the code that initializes `goodMoves` to know how the input looks? Can you also describe how shoudl your strings be broken into lines? You say that your method 'prints' modified versions of the strings but I don't see any sysouts in your code, nor any new line characters appended.

Comment: I call the method, named makePicture in the main method of my code: System.out.println(makePicture(goodMoves));

Comment: You should really give us exact samples of input and output. This code is hard to look at and debug.

Comment: Should I make "The first string "3,3,L" should print MMMCCCL" more clearer?

Comment: I'm saying you should provide us with an exact `ArrayList<String> goodMoves` and then tell us what the output should be for it.

Comment: Updated along with improved code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an if structure that is unnecessary. You have `if (boatPos == 'L')` and then you do something, then have `else` and then do the exact same thing. So just remove the if structure and do the thing.

So change your for loop to this:

```
// Use input to create printout
for (String output: goodMoves) {

    // Get numbers/character at each index of string
    char missNum = output.charAt(0);
    char cannNum = output.charAt(2);
    char boatPos = output.charAt(4);

    // Print number of M's and C's then concatenate them together
    missString = new String(new char[missNum]).replace("\0", "M");
    cannString = new String(new char[cannNum]).replace("\0", "C");

    // Concatenate both strings
    moveString = missString + cannString + boatPos + "\n";
}
```

Notice that on the last line, I added a `"\n"` to it. That is the newline character. It will print a new line after each `moveString` is calculated. If you need the line break to be somewhere else (I don't understand your code fully), then move it elsewhere. But adding a line break is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

try this `moveString = missString + cannString + boatPos +",";`

also, do this
`return moveString.subString(0,moveString.length()-1);` it will remove last comma from string.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, I need to print each statement on a line. Your method will separate them with commas.

Comment: For new line try this `System.out.println(missString + cannString + boatPos);`

Comment: Ok, I got it. Problem is with this line 
`missString = new String(new char[missNum]).replace("\0", "M");
         cannString = new String(new char[cannNum]).replace("\0", "C");`
Replace this with `for(int i=0;i<Character.getNumericValue(missNum);i++){
          moveString +="M";
         }
         for(int i=0;i<Character.getNumericValue(cannNum);i++){
          moveString +="C";
         }moveString += boatPos;
         moveString += "\n";` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation points to do that.

Try what @Shika A just said, and at the end add + "\n". Like this:

```
moveString = missString + cannString + boatPos +"\n";
```

That will separate your statements in different lines.

Comment: In doing that, the printout was "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCR"